# External HTTPS succeed, internal HTTPS requests timeout on home server

Tags: networking, server, firewall

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04.3. I am using it to serve an API built on Flask, which goes through Gunicorn and NGINX to hit the outside world. The server works as expected for requests served over HTTP. However, with HTTPS I can only access the API on devices outside my home network. When attempting to load the API, through the domain specified by the SSL certificate, on any device connected to the home network, the request times out. This happens, without fail, even when using different domains. Outside requests succeed, internal requests time out.

I have watched the results of tcpdump and ufw logs, and internal requests seem not to be hitting those programs. I am unclear about whether there is something upstream, network level, within Ubuntu that could be blocking the request.

What I have done in an effort to resolve the issue:

- Reinstalled Ubuntu Server 22.04.3
- Configured the server to listen to two different domains (one per installation attempt), each with their own certificate.
- Confirmed that port 443 is open with online tools.
- Confirmed with my ISP that there are no blocks on that port.
- Attempted numerous configurations with UFW, and even disabling UFW and running scripts to turn off iptables (unsure if necessary).
- Turned off UFW, cleared iptables, and used iptables commands that should have been successful. Again, internally things timed out, externally things flowed as expected.
- Attempted numerous configurations with my router/modem.

Where I am stumped is that external of the network the web service is accessible. It's only when on my own wireless network that the timeout occurs. So I am confident (or as much as I can be with this interminable problem) that part is working as expected. Is this something within Ubuntu that can be solved?

This is my UFW setup:

````
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)   ```
````

Comment: "routing on a stick" may be an issue here. If you access your server using an external domain from an internal network, the request goes out to your router, and the router is supposed to route it back to the server where you have the port forwarded. Not all routers support this and there's not much you can do about it, except for replacing the router or trying to find an alternative firmware for the router. You probably have to use split DNS in your local network and serve the domain to your local clients on the internal IP. Or just use `hosts` files on the clients for this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, @raj, you are absolutely correct. I appreciate your expertise.